# Passing args to Tkinter Callback validating function in Python3, Is it possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am a newbie on Python3 and trying tkinter for first time, I recently answered to [Solving simple ODE system within tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091412/solving-simple-ode-system-within-tkinter-gui/69092018#69092018) using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-validating-entry-widget/ tips.

Now I am banging my head about how the `reg_str = mainwindow.register(callback_str)` and `e4.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))` works.

I googled and tried searches on stackoverflow but wasnt able to find an answer,

below my minimal reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar,StringVar

###############################################################################
def callback_int(input,typez=None):
    # print(typez)
    
    if input.isdigit():
        # print(input)
        return True
                          
    elif input == "":
        # print(input)
        return True
  
    else:
        print(input)
        return False

def callback_str(input, typez=None):
    
    if len(input) >=1  and input[0] == '/':
        return False
    
    if all([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input]) and input.count('/') <= 1:
        # print([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input])
        # print(input)
        return True
                          
    elif all([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input]) and input.count('.') <= 1:
        # print([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input])
        # print(input)
        return True

    else:
        print('no valid input : ',input)
        return False

def mainwindow():

    mainwindow = tk.Tk()
    mainwindow.geometry('350x350')
    
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="enter parameters below").grid(row=1)
    
    getN = IntVar()
    geti0 = IntVar()
    getr0 = IntVar()
    getbeta = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')
    getgamma = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')

    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="N").grid(row=2)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="i0").grid(row=3)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="r0").grid(row=4)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="beta").grid(row=5)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="gamma").grid(row=6)
    
    e1 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getN)
    e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = geti0)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e3 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getr0)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    e4 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getbeta)
    e4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    e5 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getgamma)
    e5.grid(row=6, column=1)
    
    reg_int = mainwindow.register(callback_int)
    reg_str = mainwindow.register(callback_str)
    
    
    e1.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e2.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e3.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e4.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))
    e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))
    
    solve = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='solve!', command=lambda: [values()]).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
 
    
    def values():
        
        readN = getN.get()
        readi0 = geti0.get()
        readr0 = getr0.get()
        readbeta = eval(getbeta.get(),{"builtins": {}})
        readgamma = eval(getgamma.get(), {"builtins": {}})
        

        
        intN = int(readN)
        inti0 = int(readi0)
        intr0 = int(readr0)
        intbeta = float(readbeta)
        intgamma = float(readgamma)
        
        
        print(intN,'\n',inti0,'\n',intr0,'\n',intbeta,'\n',intgamma)

    
 
    mainwindow.mainloop()
    
mainwindow()
```

the program opens a widget:

[image]

that ask for inputs.

first 3 Entry row are validated by `callback_int` that allows only int digits while last 2 Entry rows use `callback_str` that allow both floats like 1.5 or 0.5 and fractions like 1/7 or 5/7.

My question (sorry it took so long) is:

is there a way to pass function arguments to `callback` like `callback(typez = str)`
so that I could shorten my code using only one callback function that acts differently for my int and string values ? If I use `reg_int = mainwindow.register(callback_int(input,typez='popo'))` I got

```
line ...
if input.isdigit():

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

I am guessin the problem is in :

```
reg_int = mainwindow.register(callback_int(input,typez='popo')) #AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
reg_str = mainwindow.register(callback_str('pipi'))
```

but wasnt able to find anythiong useful , or maybe my approach is in the wrong direction

Comment: Try using `reg_int = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="popo": callback_int(input, typez=typez))` instead of what you have in your question: `reg_int = mainwindow.register(callback_int(input,typez='popo'))`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll let you know

Comment: found use of lambda here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the `lambda` statement to pass either `"str"` or `"int"` to the `typez` argument in `callback()`, so that `callback()` knows what type the `input` is. Here is the full code based on my first comment above:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar,StringVar

###############################################################################
def callback(input,typez=None):
    
    if typez == "int":
        if input.isdigit():
            # print(input)
            return True
                            
        elif input == "":
            # print(input)
            return True
    
        else:
            print(input)
            return False

    if typez == "str":
        if len(input) >=1  and input[0] == '/':
            return False
        
        if all([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input]) and input.count('/') <= 1:
            # print([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input])
            # print(input)
            return True
                            
        elif all([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input]) and input.count('.') <= 1:
            # print([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input])
            # print(input)
            return True

        else:
            print('no valid input : ',input)
            return False

def mainwindow():

    mainwindow = tk.Tk()
    mainwindow.geometry('350x350')
    
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="enter parameters below").grid(row=1)
    
    getN = IntVar()
    geti0 = IntVar()
    getr0 = IntVar()
    getbeta = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')
    getgamma = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')

    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="N").grid(row=2)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="i0").grid(row=3)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="r0").grid(row=4)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="beta").grid(row=5)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="gamma").grid(row=6)
    
    e1 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getN)
    e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = geti0)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e3 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getr0)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    e4 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getbeta)
    e4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    e5 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getgamma)
    e5.grid(row=6, column=1)
    
    reg_int = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="int": callback(input, typez=typez))
    reg_str = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="str": callback(input, typez=typez))
    
    
    e1.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e2.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e3.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P'))
    e4.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))
    e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))
    
    solve = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='solve!', command=lambda: [values()]).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
 
    
    def values():
        
        readN = getN.get()
        readi0 = geti0.get()
        readr0 = getr0.get()
        readbeta = eval(getbeta.get(),{"builtins": {}})
        readgamma = eval(getgamma.get(), {"builtins": {}})
        

        
        intN = int(readN)
        inti0 = int(readi0)
        intr0 = int(readr0)
        intbeta = float(readbeta)
        intgamma = float(readgamma)
        
        
        print(intN,'\n',inti0,'\n',intr0,'\n',intbeta,'\n',intgamma)

    
 
    mainwindow.mainloop()
    
mainwindow()
```

Comment: wow that was fast exercise, what happened to the second answer talking about e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P')) to e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P', arguments)) ??? is it not workable, was good learning to me

Comment: I'll try in the next days and approve it, thanks

Comment: @pippo1980: What's wrong with `e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P'))`? You just want to know how it works?

Comment: nope, for a few seconds another answer appeared on my screen talikng about passing args after (reg_str, '%P' , int) wasnt able to catch it entirely (dont know if it was a good or bad answer but was like a different approach from your one, so just wondering what happened to that post. It's -I am finding difficulties to get google leading me to official tkinter documentation explaining this callbacj stuff

Comment: Here is some official tkinter documentation that I've found useful in my explorations with tkinter. I hope this link still exists! [tkinter tutorial docs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html)

Comment: Hi code is fine as long as  reg_int = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="str": callback(input, typez=typez)) ,reg_str = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="int": callback(input, typez=typez)) changes to  reg_int = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="int": callback(input, typez=typez))
    reg_str = mainwindow.register(lambda input, typez="str": callback(input, typez=typez)). Edit queque is Full, just send me a comment after You make the edit and I'll accept your answer, thanks again

Comment: @pippo1980: Edited the question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yep, sure. Found the other way too, posted as answer,  not sure there is more.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks to the mysterious poster that deleted a very well explained answer ([Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)) I was able to provide another way to solve my problem . Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar,StringVar

###############################################################################

def callback(input,typez=None):
    
    if typez == "int":
        if input.isdigit():
            # print(input)
            return True
                            
        elif input == "":
            # print(input)
            return True
    
        else:
            print(input)
            return False

    if typez == "str":
        if len(input) >=1  and input[0] == '/':
            return False
        
        if all([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input]) and input.count('/') <= 1:
            # print([s.isdigit() or s =='/' for s in input])
            # print(input)
            return True
                            
        elif all([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input]) and input.count('.') <= 1:
            # print([s.isdigit() or s =='.' for s in input])
            # print(input)
            return True

        else:
            print('no valid input : ',input)
            return False

def mainwindow():

    mainwindow = tk.Tk()
    mainwindow.geometry('350x350')
    
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="enter parameters below").grid(row=1)
    
    getN = IntVar()
    geti0 = IntVar()
    getr0 = IntVar()
    getbeta = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')
    getgamma = StringVar(mainwindow, value='0')

    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="N").grid(row=2)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="i0").grid(row=3)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="r0").grid(row=4)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="beta").grid(row=5)
    tk.Label(mainwindow, text="gamma").grid(row=6)
    
    e1 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getN)
    e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = geti0)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    e3 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getr0)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    e4 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getbeta)
    e4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    e5 = tk.Entry(mainwindow,textvariable = getgamma)
    e5.grid(row=6, column=1)
    
    reg_int = mainwindow.register(callback) 
    reg_str = mainwindow.register(callback)
    
    
    e1.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
    e2.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
    e3.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
    e4.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P', 'str'))
    e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P', 'str'))
    
    solve = tk.Button(mainwindow, text='solve!', command=lambda: [values()]).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
 
    
    def values():
        
        readN = getN.get()
        readi0 = geti0.get()
        readr0 = getr0.get()
        readbeta = eval(getbeta.get(),{"builtins": {}})
        readgamma = eval(getgamma.get(), {"builtins": {}})
        

        
        intN = int(readN)
        inti0 = int(readi0)
        intr0 = int(readr0)
        intbeta = float(readbeta)
        intgamma = float(readgamma)
        
        
        print(intN,'\n',inti0,'\n',intr0,'\n',intbeta,'\n',intgamma)

    
 
    mainwindow.mainloop()
    
mainwindow()
```

It doesnt use lambda, but just passes the arg as in https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html  :

> To set up this callback, you would use these two options in the Entry constructor:

```
self.w = Entry(self, validate='all',validatecommand=(okayCommand, '%d', '%i', '%S'), ... here  my extra args ...)
```

Like:

```
e1.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
e2.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
e3.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_int, '%P', 'int'))
e4.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P', 'str'))
e5.config(validate ="key", validatecommand =(reg_str, '%P', 'str'))
```

Comment: The answer was posted by Bryan Oakley, I do not see why the answer was deleted.